# How to apply CSS to the Wordpress blog post pages without changing product pages of Woocommerce?

Tags: css, wordpress

Good morning,

I would like to modify the CSS of my blog post pages, but if I do it, that change also the Woocommerce product pages description text, because both are identified as being "p".

```css
p, ul, ol, pre, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, table, form {
    margin-bottom: 20
px
;
    line-height: 1.786em;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #2f2b35;
}
```

Example of page where I like to change the text: https://librairiedamase.com/blog/quelle-bible-choisir/

Example of page where I like not to change the text (of description): https://librairiedamase.com/boutique/sainte-ecriture/bible-expliquee-et-commentaires/commentaire-des-psaumes-2/

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to your css

```
#content > .entry > * {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    line-height: 1.786em;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #2f2b35;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, John. The result is quite perfect. The product descriptions are not affected by the new formats. Only the titles of the [account page](https://librairiedamase.com/account/edit-account/) are unfortunately not excluded from the new formats.

Comment: Should you just tell me if there is a solution to exclude new formats in the account page?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: @Kambro in the CSS in my answer above, Try changing`.entry` to `.post` and see if that works for you.

Comment: Thank you. But it does not improve anything.

Answer (score 1):

You need to prepend a single post body class before your target tags.

Example:

```
body.single-post p {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  line-height: 1.786em;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #2f2b35;}
```